# Max value by category in a sequence in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Have been trying to come up with a solution to this for a while without success.I am using SQL server 2012 and I was wondering what can I do to get the max value of the column 'row_num_by_cat' by 'id' and 'cat' partition only until a different value is found in 'cat' column or a new sequence starts in column 'row_num_by_cat'. Column 'new_count_max' in yellow shows what I am looking for.

Your help would be appreciated.

[image: data sample]

Comment: Please do not post data as images like here or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52101614/max-dates-for-each-sequence-within-partitions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `MAX(row_num) OVER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,SUM(CASE WHEN row_num > 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
         OVER(PARTITION BY id, cat ORDER BY date_col) AS grp
  FROM tab
)
SELECT *, MAX(row_num) OVER(PARTITION BY id, cat, grp) AS new_count_max
FROM cte
ORDER BY id, date_col, cat;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/RTDR23585)**